# For loop Error, not outputting my desired output

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop

Can someone please provide an explanation to me why my code is not working as I am trying to get, and what is the correct way to implement my code?

Here is my code:

```
x = [1 2 3 5; 4 3 1 3; 1 3 3 4];
y = [1 2 3 5; 4 3 1 3; 1 3 3 4];

columns = 3;
for i = 1:columns
    correct = 0;
    for j = 1:4
        if x(i,j) == y(i,j)
           correct = correct + 1;
        end
        all_correct(columns,1) = correct;
    end
end
```

When I run this code, I get the answer for all_correct to be the following:
 `all_correct = [0;0;4;]`

I know this is wrong, the correct answer should be:
 `all_correct = [4;4;4;]`

This is because all x elements are exactly the same to all y elements. I'm not too sure what is wrong with my code, in order to achieve my desired output.

Comment: I would remove the key-words matlab-deployment and matlab-compiler. They have nothing to do with your code.

Comment: Furthermore, I would suggest to delete the duplicate of your question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73683637/why-is-the-matlab-code-not-outputting-my-desired-output).

Comment: And you confuse columns and rows when naming your variables. You actually have four columns and three rows.

Comment: Besides the use of `columns` instead of `i` as discussed in the answer below, you should also move this assignment outside of the loop over `j`, otherwise you’ll assign repeatedly to the same array element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a typo in your code, it should be `all_correct(i,1) = correct;` instead of `all_correct(columns,1) = correct;`.

As `columns` is always `3`, you only assign to the third position in `all_correct`.

*[Edit] Moreover, as noticed and commented by Cris Luengo below your question, you could also move `all_correct(i,1) = correct;` outside the loop over `j`.*

An *improved version* of your code would be:

```
all_correct = sum( x == y, 2 )
```

Explanation:

- `x == y` provides a logical array showing where `x` and `y` are equal.
- `sum( x == y, 2 )` the sums up over the rows.